# How do you specify a common root directory for all libname references in SAS?

Tags: sas, stata

In SAS, is there a way to assign a common root directory for all libname references, or combine an explicit folder path with a libname?

In Stata, I would do this by:

```
global rootfolder "C:/user"
*and then:
use "$rootfolder/subfolder1/file.dta"
use "$rootfolder/subfolder2/file.dta"
use "$rootfolder/subfolder3/file.dta"
```

Thus, I only have to specify a single root folder only once, and then explicitly specify each subfolder on the fly.

But in SAS, I would have to create the libname three times:

```
libname subfolder1 "C:/user/subfolder1";
libname subfolder1 "C:/user/subfolder2";
libname subfolder1 "C:/user/subfolder3";
*and then:;
proc contents data=subfolder1.file; run;
proc contents data=subfolder2.file; run;
proc contents data=subfolder3.file; run;
```

So is there a way to do what I can do in Stata, but in SAS? E.g., something like:

```
*the following code does not work, but I want to do something like this:;
libname rootfolder "C:/user";
*and then:;
proc contents data=rootfolder/subfolder1.file; run;
proc contents data=rootfolder/subfolder2.file; run;
proc contents data=rootfolder/subfolder3.file; run;
```

Thanks

Comment: Theres an option, SASINITIALFOLDER and you set the default path in your config file. Not sure this is what you need but where I'd start.

Comment: Off topic but in Stata I have been doing `cd C:/user` and then simply `use ./subfolder1/file.dta`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as specifying the default directory for the SAS process with the SASINITIALFOLDER option, you can also use the SAS Macro facility like so:

```
%let rootfolder=C:/user;
libname sub1 "&rootfolder/subfolder1";
libname sub2 "&rootfolder/subfolder2";
libname sub3 "&rootfolder/subfolder3";
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create librefs and reference datasets using LIBREF.MEMBER syntax.  You can just reference the dataset using a quoted physical filename instead.

```
%let rootfolder=C:/user;
data want ;
   set "&rootfolder/subfolder1/file.sas7bdat"
       "&rootfolder/subfolder2/file.sas7bdat"
       "&rootfolder/subfolder3/file.sas7bdat"
   ;
run;
```

You can even leave off the `.sas7bdat` and SAS will find the file.

Comment: This is also an answer and what I was looking for (I wish I could mark two), thank you.